# ExtJS Grid selection not refreshing after store update

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs6-classic, selectionmodel, extjs6.5.1

I have a grid with 2 rows, when removing the first row from the store the grid updates and looks as expected. But the old selection is still active with data that should not exist anymore.

When doubleclicking (the new first row) in the grid, it opens the old data.

After updating the store I have tried:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
grid.getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
grid.getSelectionModel().clearSelections();
```

This is ExtJS version 6.5, classic

Comment: May you provide fiddle sample?

Comment: I tried to do a fiddle but it took to much time. Solved the problem in the code by looping through the selection and comparing with the store, If the record wasn't in the store i returned the function prematurally.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bind in grid. like

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Grid',{
     bind:{
           selection: '{selection}'
},
.....codes    })

    Ext.create('Ext.app.ViewModel',{
alias: 'viewmodel.aliasname',
data:{selection: null}})
```

now update or reload store selection is null.